# Lack of WiFi in 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless

So I recently had ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on my machine, Thinkpad X1 Carbon 4th gen, when I ended up wanting to do a clean install on. Never before have I had problems with the wifi but lo and behold with a clean install of 16.04 LTS the "enable wifi" option is gone.

When booting from usb wifi works fine, but on the installed version it doesnt for whatever reason. When using `sudo lshw -c network` I get the `*-network  UNCLAIMED` message for my Intel 8260.

I've found one or two relatively sketchy workaround but I'm not sure hwy that's necessary as it was functioning no more than hours ago?

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` returns:

```
morten@mortenThinkPad:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for morten: 
[    3.294932] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.309235] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309247] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309257] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309267] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-30.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309276] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-29.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309285] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-28.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309295] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309304] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309314] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309323] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309332] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309341] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.309343] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    3.309347] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-8000C-22
[    3.309349] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-8000C-33
[    3.309351] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not quite sure how you got installed without the correct firmware. Let's fix it. With a temporary working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.157.15_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.